# r-Mapview non reponsive with large simple feature dataframe?

Tags: r, sp, sf, mapview

I am trying to visualize a large **sf dataframe** with around 1000 rows containing **linestrings** with **mapview**::mapview() in **R**. Unfortunately a warning comes up when I perform the command:

```
mapview(data.frame)

Warning message:
In leaflet_sfc(sf::st_geometry(x), map = map, zcol = zcol, color = clrs,  :
  the supplied feature layer has more points/vertices than the set threshold.
  using special rendering function, hence things may not behave as expected from a standard leaflet map,
  e.g. you will likely need to zoom in to popup-query features

  to see the number of points/vertices of the layer use 'npts(x)'
  to see the threshold for the feature type use 'mapview:::getMaxFeatures(x)'
  to adjust the threshold use argument 'maxpoints'
```

And then I try to export as html and I get:

## R code execution error

And the saved file is 0 kb.

Is there a fix or a workaround with some other function from the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by adding maxpoints argument:

```
mapview::mapview(data.frame, maxpoints = 1000000)
```

Seems this increased the previously set threshold for plotting maximum number of features.